# Installation problems:Visio Professional 2013

Tags: office-2013-preview, microsoft-visio-2013, microsoft-office-2013

I purchased Microsoft ***Visio Professional 2013*** for my **Windows 7 64 Bit**, i have installed Microsoft Office 2013 Preview (64 Bit) and i had also Microsoft **Visio** 2013 **Preview** but i uninstalled it (Visio Preview) with Revo Uninstaller Pro. I want to keep the Microsoft Office Preview 2013 a little bit more cause i need it but also want to install Microsoft Visio 2013. When i am about to install Visio Professional 2013 i get this massage:

> Microsoft Office 2013 does not support upgrading form a preview
>   version of Microsoft Office 2013.You must uninstall these preview
>   versions of Microsoft Office 2013 products and associated technologies:
>
> - Office 15 Click-to-Run Extensibility Component
> - Office 15 Click-to-Run Licensing Component

The question is after i uninstall Office 2013 preview and install Visio 2013 Professional will i be able to install Office 2013 preview again or will i need to purchase the Windows Office 2013 ?

[image: Microsoft Office 2013 does not support upgrading form a preview version of Microsoft Office 2013.You must uninstall these preview versions of Microsoft Office 2013 products]

Comment: The only advice we can give you is to try it since your situation is unique in that you want to keep a preview version of Office installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preview is not a final product and it is a test drive. You cannot install full and final releases when there is a preview. So simply remove it. You cannot install preview on top of the pro versions (even if its a different product). Which could cause multiple issues. Setup will prevent the installation most probably (as we encountered the same issue with earlier products). You can run old versions but full versions. :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so that means basically that i have to **uninstall**  Office 2013 preview so that i can install the purchased version of Visio Professional 2013. Ok thanks. Then i will see to finish my Work with Office 2013 preview and then uninstall it.

Comment: You are quite welcome!